# How can I run command in Microsoft Exchange Server Powershell through Python script?

Tags: python, powershell, exchange-server

I want to check the number of mailbox in Microsoft Exchange Server. This command works fine in standard cmd.exe:

```
"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -command ". 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\bin\RemoteExchange.ps1'; Connect-ExchangeServer -auto ; Get-Mailbox | Measure-Object"
```

Output is

```
...
Count    : 3
Average  :
Sum      :
Maximum  :
Minimum  :
Property :
```

Then I am going to code it in Python, using "-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned":

```
cmd = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe
 -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
 -command \". 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft\\Exchange Server\\V14\\bin\\RemoteExchange.ps1'; Connect-ExchangeServer -auto; Get-Mailbox | Measure-Object\""
os.system(cmd)
```

There is lots of error about loading RemoteExchange.ps1 file.

```
Get-ItemProperty : Cannot find path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ExchangeServer\v14\Setup' because it does not exist.
At C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\bin\RemoteExchange.ps1:46 char:34
+ $global:exbin = (get-itemproperty <<<<  HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ExchangeServer\v14\Setup).MsiInstallPath + "bin\"
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (HKLM:\SOFTWARE\...erver\v14\Setup:String) [Get-ItemProperty], ItemNotFo
   undException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetItemPropertyCommand

...

The Exchange types file wasn't loaded because not all of the required files could be found.
Update-TypeData : Cannot find path 'C:\Users\administrator.SCCM01\bin\Exchange.partial.Types.ps1xml' because it does no
t exist.
At C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\bin\RemoteExchange.ps1:104 char:16
+ Update-TypeData <<<<  -PrependPath $partialTypeFile
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (bin\Exchange.partial.Types.ps1xml:String) [Update-TypeData], ItemNotF
   oundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypesPrependPathException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.UpdateTypeDataCommand
```

Although the welcome screen of Exchange Management Shell appears, it failed to load RemoteExchange.ps1, and "Get-Mailbox" command is not working at all.

I guess I must have missed something important. How can I solve this problem? Please help.

**Edit**: Why should I add `-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned` in Python script? If I do not do that, it will result in a different error:

```
File C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\bin\RemoteExchange.ps1 cannot be loaded because the execution of scripts is disabled on this system. Please see "get-help about_signing" for more details.
```

Refer to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6901856/invoking-a-powershell-script-from-python), and `RemoteSigned` is better than `Unrestricted`. Both of them work in cmd.exe, but not work in Python script.

Comment: Why are you using two *different* command lines? Shouldn't you execute the one you know to work via Python?

Comment: Two command lines are the same except I have to use -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned option to work partially, otherwise, powershell.exe doesn't work at all.

Comment: Does the input given to Python work on cmd and vice versa? Do you have the same execution policies? Are you running the commands on same or different computers and/or user accounts?

Comment: It works on cmd.exe, same execution policies, same computer and same account.

Comment: How come you need the `-ExecutionPolicy` on Python then? There is something amiss on your setup. Can you run any Powershell script via Python without extra parameters?

Comment: Also just for clarity, is it going to be easier to use raw strings instead of escapes, just by way of reducing another source of typos/error potential?

Comment: @vonPryz I just update the question at the end of it, to explain why it's important to add `-ExecutionPolicy` option.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the exact same problem under slightly different circumstances but the error message was identical. I was trying to provision MS Exchange via [Puppet and Powershell scripts](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/windows/running.html#file-system-redirection-in-64-bit-windows-versions). You are suffering from the side effects of the [File System Redirector (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which runs silently. Apparently 64-bit registry keys can't be accessed by 32-bit programs and the File System Redirector will change things up on you without you even knowing it.

I found this to be an [elegant solution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for my situation:

> 32-bit applications can access the native system directory by
>   substituting %windir%\Sysnative for %windir%\System32. WOW64
>   recognizes Sysnative as a special alias used to indicate that the file
>   system should not redirect the access. This mechanism is flexible and
>   easy to use, therefore, it is the recommended mechanism to bypass file
>   system redirection. Note that 64-bit applications cannot use the
>   Sysnative alias as it is a virtual directory not a real one.

Comment: How can I bypass the file system redirection or registry redirection in Python script and py2exe compiler?

Comment: The file system redirection (FSR) works automatically for paths that contain "system32". If you are running a 32-bit program, replace "system32" with "sysnative" and it will force the OS to use the 64-bit version.

For example, I was using "C:\windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" to access the registry via a powershell script. The registry keys I wanted so happened to be 64-bit and the FSR was causing problem until I changed it to "c:\windows\sysnative\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"